# Maximum or minimum value of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The following summarized discussion appears in almost all the books of calculus/ real analysis:

If $f$ is a continuous real valued function on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then it attains maximum as well as minimum value at some points of the domain.  If it is differentiable on $(a,b)$, then the points at which maximum and minimum value are attained are among $a,b$ and those $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$.

**Q.** If we just assume continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$, is there no way to find maximum or minimum values of function? If there is no way, how do we convince it?

(After discussion with some people, partial answer to above question was that, the proof, of showing  $f$ has maximum or minimum value, is not constructive. But, we can raise question: *one proof is non-constructive; other proofs can be constructive. Then?*)

Comment: Points where $f'(c)$ are *relative* extrema. Little to do with Weirstrass theorem about the bounds of a continuous function on a closed interval. Weirstrass theorem is important from a theoretical point of view, not from a practical one